# How do I get a slanted \sum symbol?

Tags: symbols, slanted

I want to use a slanted `\sum` symbol denoting a different meaning from summation. How do I get a slanted `\sum` symbol?

[image]

Comment: What is the intended meaning? Please reconsider this as the use of 2 very similar symbols, only distinguished by the fact that one is slanted, will be extremely confusing, as well as typographically bad. In mathematical typesetting, things of the same kind get typeset in similar ways e.g. all functions, all operators, all variables... in upright, in italic, in ...

Comment: Can you draw what you're looking for?  If it's a simple rotation, then the linked answers your question.  If it's truly 'oblique', then perhaps not.

Comment: @cfr This is not duplicate, because rotating isn't slanting.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using pdfTeX then you can try this code:

```
\def\itsum{\mathop{\mathpalette\itsumA{}\phantom\sum}}
\def\itsumA#1#2{\pdfsave\pdfliteral{1 0 .2 1 0 0 cm}\rlap{$#1\sum$}\pdfrestore}

$\sum_i^5 \itsum_j^{\,7} a_{ij}$
```

[image: sumy]

Comment: Also works with LuaTeX 'out of the box' (those primitives are carried forward as-is)

Comment: @JosephWright Of course. I "assume" :-) that LuaTeX users know that pdfTeX is included here.

Comment: Actually you can generalize it with something like `{if pdf}{<\pdfliteral code>}{<\special code>}`

Comment: @percusse I do something similar in my macros. If `\pdfliteral` isn't accessible then I define it as `\def\pdfliteral#1{\special{pdf:literal #1}}`. This allows me to keep the `\pdfliteral`-dependent macros unchanged.

Answer (score 6):

One way to do it is to use a slanted capital sigma. By using the `scalerel` package, one can make that symbol (approximately) the same size as the original `\sum` operator:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\itsum}{\scalerel*{\mathit{\Sigma}}{\sum}}
\begin{document}
\[
\sum_i x_i\quad\itsum_i x_i
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why did you make the slanted version larger?

Comment: @cfr The reason the slanted one is larger can be determined by executing `\fboxsep=0pt\fbox{$\mathit{\Sigma}$}\fbox{$\displaystyle\sum$}` (with the `scalerel` package loaded).  The `\sum` has a built in padding above and below the glyph, which is absent in the `\Sigma` (`\mathit` or otherwise).  Thus, the `\scalrel`ed `\Sigma` is grown to the size of the padded `\sum`, which is slightly larger than the actual glyph.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use `\varSigma` as `$\varSigma$`

[image]

Comment: Included in the `amsmath` package, but strangely not in the [Comprehensive list](https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Comment: @SandyG Interesting. Maybe because the uppercase slanted Greek letters are just part of the OML encoding, but that's not really a reason not to mention them.

Answer (score 3):

With `l3draw` (and the standard `\mathpalette`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{l3draw}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\slsum}{}{%
  \DOTSB
  \mathop{\vphantom{\sum}\mathpalette\slsum@\relax}
  \slimits@
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\slsum@}{mm}{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{%
    \xslantobject{$\m@th#1\sum$}{0.4}%
  }}%
}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\xslantobject}{mm}
 {
  \draw_begin:
  \draw_transform_xslant:n { #2 }
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { #1 }
  \draw_box_use:N \l_tmpa_box
  \draw_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\sum_{i\ge0}\slsum_{i\ge0}
\]
\begin{center}
$\sum\slsum$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]