# Is there a way to slant math symbols?

Tags: italic, slanted

Let's consider the following sentence:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
We often call these players \emph{spoiler} and \emph{duplicator}, \emph{\'Elo\"ise} and \emph{Ab\'elard} or $\exists$ and $\forall$.
\end{document}
```

What I'd want now is a slanted version of the `\forall` and the `\exists` symbols, is there a way to do this (some sort of `\mathsl` or something like that)?

Or would you say that this really is too ugly?

Comment: I'd say that this should be prohibited!

Comment: That's what I thought as well, though I was curious on how it would look.

Comment: In case you want to see some related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/220434/14757

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example uses slanting via TikZ:

```
\tikz[
  baseline=(X.base),
  inner sep=0pt,
  transform canvas={xslant=cos(#1)},
] \node (X) {#2};%
```

The slant angle is `#1` and the slanted material is in `#2`. For some unknown reason, the bounding box is pretty wrong, the box is horizontally centered at the baseline with much shorter height. Therefore the definition
`\xslant` sets the bounding box manually.

The slant angle can be given by the optional argument. The default is 76 (measured from the slanted upper case I of Computer Modern fonts).

The macro `\xslantmath` is an extended version, which puts the argument in math and respects the current math style.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\xslant}[2][76]{%
  \begingroup
    \sbox0{#2}%
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\wdslant{\the\wd0 + cos(#1)*\the\wd0}%
    \leavevmode
    \hbox to \wdslant{\hss
      \tikz[
        baseline=(X.base),
        inner sep=0pt,
        transform canvas={xslant=cos(#1)},
      ] \node (X) {\usebox0};%
      \hss
      \vrule width 0pt height\ht0 depth\dp0 %
    }%
  \endgroup
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\xslantmath}{}
\def\xslantmath#1#{%
  \@xslantmath{#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\@xslantmath}[2]{%
  % #1: optional argument for \xslant including brackets
  % #2: math symbol
  \ensuremath{%
    \mathpalette{\@@xslantmath{#1}}{#2}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@@xslantmath}[3]{%
  % #1: optional argument for \xslant including brackets
  % #2: math style
  % #3: math symbol
  \xslant#1{$#2#3\m@th$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
We often call these players \emph{spoiler} and \emph{duplicator} or
\xslantmath{\exists} and \xslantmath{\forall}$\!$.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

Ugly as hell. `;-)`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\slantflip}[1]{%
  \raisebox{\depth}{%
    \scalebox{1}[-1]{%
      \scalebox{-1}[1]{\slshape\sffamily#1}%
    }%
  }\negthinspace
}

\newcommand{\allsl}{\slantflip{A}}
\newcommand{\allex}{\slantflip{E}}

\begin{document}

\allsl{} and \allex{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, ugly solutions for ugly problems, those are the best