# How do I get a slanted \sum symbol with a suitable size in XeLaTex?

Tags: math-operators

I want to use a slanted `\sum` symbol denoting a different meaning from summation. I searched it in the TSE but didn't find a satisfactory answer: @[summer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220436/140814) gave one with a too large size and @[wipet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220482/140814) gave one in PDFLaTex only. **Then how do I get a slanted \sum symbol with a suitable size in XeLaTex?**

[image]

Comment: What about placement of limits? Anyway, I don't think that this is a suitable symbol.

Comment: @egreg Since I need four symbols for different generalized products, then the slanted one may be necessary, and hence the slanted sum is also necessary ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Ti*k*Z as suggested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/326144/4427

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\slantedsum}{\DOTSB\slantedsum@\slimits@}
\newcommand{\slantedsum@}[1]{\mathop{\mathpalette\slantedsum@@\relax}}
\newcommand{\slantedsum@@}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{%
    \tikz \node[inner sep=0pt,xslant=0.25] {$\m@th#1\sum$};%
  }}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\sum\slantedsum
\]
\begin{center}
$\sum\slantedsum$ \\
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\fbox{$\displaystyle\sum$}%
\fbox{$\displaystyle\slantedsum$}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good solution which gives a way to slant all the large operators! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

This will not work for you in xelatex.  But for other users, if they use pdflatex, then use of `\slantbox` is an option.  With `scalerel`, it is made to work across math styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][0]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\foo}{\ThisStyle{\slantbox[.15]{$\SavedStyle\sum$}}}

\begin{document}
\[
\foo_{i=3}^{6}(f^2(i))
\]

This is inline: \(\foo_{i=3}^{6}(f^2(i)) \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've read your post before my post. A good solution in PDFLaTeX!